# How to save QMenu settings to external config file and how to reapply them later

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmainwindow

The code below saves, reads and re-applies the config settings on every application's start and exit.
Aside from the main window's size I want to be able to save the `QMenu` state as well.

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.iniFile=os.path.join( os.path.expanduser('~'), 'gui.ini')
        self.settings=QSettings(self.iniFile, QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.onStart()  
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        result = QMessageBox.question(self,"Confirm window","Are you sure you want to close the window?",QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,QMessageBox.No)
        if result == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.onExit()
            self.destroy(True)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def onExit(self):
        self.settings.setValue("WindowGeometry", self.saveGeometry())
        self.settings.setValue("WindowState", self.saveState())
        print "Success: gui.ini was saved as %s"%self.iniFile

    def onStart(self):    
        windowGeometry=self.settings.value("WindowGeometry")
        if windowGeometry:
            windowGeometry=windowGeometry.toByteArray()
            if windowGeometry:
                self.restoreGeometry(windowGeometry) 
        else:
            self.resize(200,50)

        windowState=self.settings.value("WindowState")
        if windowState:
            windowState=windowState.toByteArray()
            if windowState:
                self.restoreState(windowState) 

class Window(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()        
        menu=QMenu()
        menu1=menu.addAction("Menu01")     
        menu2=menu.addAction("Menu02")
        menu1.triggered.connect(self.onTrigger)
        menu2.triggered.connect(self.onTrigger)
        menu1.setCheckable(True)
        menu2.setCheckable(True)

        button=QToolButton(self)
        button.setText('Click Here')

        button.setPopupMode(button.InstantPopup)
        button.setMenu(menu)

    def onTrigger(self, arg):
        print arg, type(arg)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
view=Window() 
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you think you mean by the "state" of a QMenu?  That is not defined by Qt (so far as I can see), so it's up to you.  You can store anything in QSettings provided you convert it to the proper format.

Comment: I would like to save the states of all Menu's QActions such as their checked status. So when the application exits with some menu actions being checked the same menu's actions are checked when the app starts next time. Same applies for unchecked menu actions.

Comment: First look at [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#checked-prop) then look at [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#setValue)

Comment: `dictionary={'Menu1':True,'Menu2':False,'Menu3':True}; settings.setValue("Menus", dictionary); data=settings.value("Menus")`

Comment: `dictionary=data.toPyObject()`

Comment: `for action in menu.actions():  value=dictionary.get(action.text()); action.setChecked(value)`

Comment: The second comment could go to the question and the last comments to an answer.